# MariaDB: Error 121 trying to add a foreign key but no foreign key is present

Tags: mariadb

as part of a migration process, I've got a SQL script that adds several foreign key constraints to the database schema. When I run it in our development environment, I get an error 121 and the InnoDB log says: "A foreign key constraint of name `database`.`FK_Name` already exists.". But when I run either one of

```
select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';

select *
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
where CONSTRAINT_NAME like '%FK_Name%'
```

I get empty results, so I understand there's no existing foreign key.

I don't understand what's going on. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

UPDATE:

Sorry, it may have been a residue of the failed migration process: I can add the foreign key on a freshly restored db.

Comment: Are you checking it as `root`? Otherwise, maybe there is a table with the constraint which you don't have access to, then it wouldn't be shown in the result set from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. Check your permissions on the schema.

Comment: I've tried both as application user and as root

Answer (score 0):

It may have been a residue of the failed migration process: I can add the foreign key on a freshly restored db.